# list hosts of ssh config file with helm when using ssh.el

Tags: helm, ssh

I use [ssh-mode](https://github.com/ieure/ssh-el) when I need to work on remote hosts. As I only establish ssh connections to hosts, that are stored in my ssh config file I want this list of hosts to be displayed in a `helm-buffer`.

Answer (score 1):

I have found [How to write helm extensions](http://wikemacs.org/wiki/How_to_write_helm_extensions). Only thing I had to do was return the list of known hosts with `pcmpl-ssh-hosts` for the `helm-source`.

```
(setq ssh-helm-source
      `((name . "Known hosts")
        (candidates . ,(pcmpl-ssh-hosts))
        (action . (lambda (candidate)
                    (helm-marked-candidates)))))

(defun helm-ssh ()
  (interactive)
  (ssh
   (mapconcat 'identity
              (helm :sources '(ssh-helm-source))
              ",")))
```